# Cannot boot beyond "encryption" screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, encryption

There seems to be a big problem with one of my Ubuntu installations.

After the regular update that took place without problems, I cannot access the OS anymore. I am submitting the encryption key correctly after booting, but after that I just see a black screen.

I don't have important stuff in there and maybe I will reinstall, but the problem is that all of a sudden the OS is not accessible. This is something that shouldn't happen and I was wondering if someone can guide me through a "recovery" process, because I couldn't find a proper solution anywhere.

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you have? Do you have any idea about what packages were upgraded? And do you use the built-in encryption system in Ubuntu, the one in your BIOS, or a third-party one? Could you also boot from a LiveUSB and check the logs?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was using the 14.04 and cannot recall which packaged were upgraded. I am using the built-in encryption system and the boot from LiveUSB didn't show anything in the logs (or I couldn't see anything). Do you have an advise?